# Не могу создать второй блок

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Всем привет! Я - новичок в веб. Решил сверстать сайт-портфолио для себя и наткнулся на такую проблему - не могу создать второй блок для конента. Сделал параллакс эффект (код из иннета), а остальные блоки почему-то уходят под него. Может кто знает почему?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Portfolio of Almas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div>
          <h1>Portfolio</h1>
          <small>of Almas Qajymuratuly</small>
      </div>
      <svg class="arrows">
          <path class="a1" d="M0 0 L30 32 L60 0"></path>
          <path class="a2" d="M0 20 L30 52 L60 20"></path>
          <path class="a3" d="M0 40 L30 72 L60 40"></path>
        </svg>
    </header>

<div class="aboutme">
<h1>hi</h1>
</div>

    <footer class="footer"></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

'

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,300i,400,400i,800,800i,900,900i&display=swap");
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  perspective: 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "Corn Demo", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}



header {
  margin-top: -35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100vw;
}

header::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: center;
  min-height: 100vh;

  background-image: url("/img/822464.jpg");

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s;
  /*Parallax*/
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

h1 {
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: "Corn Demo" 900, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}

header small {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Corn Demo" 400, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  word-spacing: 10px;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.menu li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Corn" 300, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.arrows {
  transform-style: inherit;
    width: 60px;
    height: 72px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.arrows path {
    stroke: #fff;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 2px;  
    animation: arrow 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: arrow 2s infinite; 
}

@keyframes arrow
{
0% {opacity:0}
40% {opacity:1}
80% {opacity:0}
100% {opacity:0}
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrow /*Safari and Chrome*/
{
0% {opacity:0}
40% {opacity:1}
80% {opacity:0}
100% {opacity:0}
}

.arrows path.a1 {
    animation-delay:-1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:-1s; /* Safari 和 Chrome */
}

.arrows path.a2 {
    animation-delay:-0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:-0.5s; /* Safari 和 Chrome */
}

.arrows path.a3 {   
    animation-delay:0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0s; /* Safari 和 Chrome */
}

.aboutme{
 border: 5px red;
  background-image: url("/img/4insta.jpg");
}



@font-face {
  font-family: "Corn Demo";
  src: url("/fonts/Corn/CornDemo-Regular.eot");
  src: local("/fonts/Corn/CornDemo-Regular"),
    url("/fonts/Corn/CornDemo-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/fonts/Corn/CornDemo-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("/fonts/Corn/CornDemo-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/fonts/Corn/CornDemo-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютно спозиционированный элемент выпадает из потока, т.к у вас relative явно не задан,ваш псевдоэлемент позиционируется относительно body.
Все что вы пытаетесь создать ниже появляется за ним.
Используйте какую нибудь обертку